# How can I find the folders with specific permission?

Tags: linux

How can I find the folders with specific permission in Linux?

I want to find all these folders and files in Linux so that I can change them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
find . -type d -perm 0700 -user apache -ls
```

change 0700 to the permission you want.

Comment: thnx a lot , and how can I say, find all folders with specific user, for example all folders that their owner is apache

Comment: `man find`. Skip to the part which states `-user uname  File is owned by user` (in your case user apache).

Comment: I have edited my answer to include username

Answer (score 2):

Not with a single command I believe. You could try something like this:

```
dir=.
username=$USER

{ find "$dir" -user $username -perm -u=w ;
  for gid in `id -G $username`; do 
    find "$dir" -group $gid -perm -g=w ;
  done
  find "$dir" -perm -o=w ;
} | sort | uniq
```

**Edit:** The above will list all files writable to the given user (as you originally asked), not only files with specific permissions (like `rwx------`).

Comment: It depends if you consider 'find -perm xxxx -user apache -exec chmod yyyy' a single command. (I am not sure if I need to consider that one or two commands)

Comment: impressive, thnx a lot ...